# Unity3d Script from Native Android Service

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-service, unityscript

I have a native Android service running in the background that needs to interface with a Unity3D script. I'm aware of the following method:

```
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(String gameObject, String arg1, String arg2)
```

But it requires a gameObject parameter. Since the service is running in the background, I can't be 100% sure that a gameObject attached to a particular scene has not yet been destroyed. Is this a fair assumption (since the user might not even be in the app)?

If so, is there a way to instantiate a gameObject that is never destroyed? Is there any other way to call a unity script from native Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about how to call unityscript from native code. But you can make a `GameObject` stay alive until manual removal by using the `DontDestroyOnLoad` function on it. Example:

```
void Awake() 
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

More info from [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

Comment: More info here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/654954/c-script-from-native-android-service.html